# Sphinx get agent schema

Tags: sphinx

it's my first question, so forgive my errors:). 
As a framework I'm using Yii2 and at the beginning of any requests, I have a problem of receiving an answer of distributed index agent in sphinx by command:

```
DESCRIBE `10.0.0.22:9312:indexName`;
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting IDENT (or 49 other tokens) near '`10.0.0.22:9312:indexName`'
```

My distributed conf:

```
index indexName {
    type = distributed
    agent = 10.0.13.24:9312|10.0.0.22:9312:indexName
    ha_strategy = noerrors
}
```

Other conf:

```
index indexName
{
    type            = rt

    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/indexName

    rt_field        = code
    rt_field        = title
    rt_field        = article
    rt_field        = docket

    rt_attr_uint        = code
    rt_attr_string      = title
    rt_attr_string      = article
    rt_attr_string      = docket

    morphology = lemmatize_ru, stem_enru
    charset_table   = 0..9, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, _
    blend_chars     = +, &, @
    dict        = keywords
    min_word_len    = 1
    min_prefix_len  = 1
}
```

My searchd conf is default.

Also I have a problem of queries where fields names with backquotes, such as:

```
SELECT `id`, weight() as relevance from indexName where match('asus');
```

I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): index indexName: agent 10.0.0.22:9312: remote error: select: syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting $end near '`, weight() as relevance'
```

I also tried this queries in console and the same errors appears. But if I make simple queries like "SELECT * FROM indexName WHERE MATCH('asus')" everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas pretty sure sphinx can't 'proxy' though 'DESCRIBE' requests. You can only describe local indexes, and the distributed index itself (to get its components).

Cant get the feilds/attributes of the remote indexes, the client would have to directly connect to the remote agent to get the setting. (although can of course get a list of attributes at least, by running a query (SELECT * FROM dist LIMIT 1)

---

As for the issue with quotes, its a known bug, but dont know what the status is on fixing it. Running a query without backquotes usually works better.

Comment: Thanx for the answer

Comment: Not sure its relevent, but thought to mention it for completeness: Just realised you can get the list for Fields for a distributed index via SphinxAPI (the 'fields' array is populated even for distributed indexes) - one of the fiew things possible in the API, not in SphinxQL.

Comment: Thanx for addition, but I use extension for Yii2 which uses only SphinxQl,

Comment: Also I found another workaround, just added to distributed conf local index, which is empty, but have schema. So I get schema from local and results from agents